# Remove unnecessary rounding

Tags: java, decimal, rounding

How do I get the correct not rounded result as what I get in excel?

```
public void testdivide_largenumber() {
    double result;
    double number = 8789700;
    double divisor = 3200;
    BigDecimal number_BD = new BigDecimal(number, MathContext.DECIMAL64);
    BigDecimal divisor_BD = new BigDecimal(divisor, MathContext.DECIMAL64);

    BigDecimal result_BD;

    result = (double) (number / divisor);
    result_BD = number_BD.divide(divisor_BD);

    System.out.println("double result should be 2746.78124999656="+ result );
    System.out.println("BigDecimal result should be 2746.78124999656="+ result_BD );
}
```

Result:

`double` result should be `2746.78124999656=2746.78125`

`BigDecimal` result should be `2746.78124999656=2746.78125`

Comment: why do you know it *should be* `2746.78124999656`? Because `3200` divdes `8789700` perfectly into `2746.78125`

Comment: I have voted to close as off-topic. This question is based on incorrect result to begin with. Since there is no problem, this won't be useful in the futur. As a note, I don't reproduce the same result as you with Excel 2010. `8789700|3200|=A1/B1` gives `2746,78125`. Last thing, check with Google if you want [8789700/3200](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=GK_-Wt30C4--kwWIhJe4Ag&q=8789700%2F3200&oq=8789700%2F3200&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3014.5512.0.6023.12.12.0.0.0.0.78.682.12.12.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.5.333...0j0i5i30k1.0.brnv-ouFKB4).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Excel 2016 or 2010 - use the shift decimal places up till 11-12 places, you will see it.

Comment: Re-edit, excel is not wrong. was trying these numbers: 2745.31578947*1900+2748.92307692*1300, which displays 8789700 in excel.

Comment: Final answer: excel gives 2746.78124999656, double gives 2746.781249996562 and Big decimal gives 2746.7812499965621875

Answer (score 1):

As @Lino pointed out in his comment, `8789700/3200 = 2746.78125`. The result that you got from excel has floating point rounding errors, java is correct.

Comment: Can't belive Excel did such bad answer. Checked in LibreOffice Calc and got `2746.78125`.

Comment: I don't believe excel has any problems either ... this is used for accoutings for long enough... This would be notice by now.

Comment: @AxelH the relative error seems to be in the order of 10<sup>-12</sup>, so it would be cents for tens of billions of euros.

Comment: Excel is technically not wrong, this is the result of floating point arithmetics.

Comment: It's human error, i didn't see the decimal from 8789699.999989. Excel does not have floating point rounding errors.